# Javascript Pop Ups

Tags: javascript, timeout, popup, onload

My boss has asked for a page that will not change to have two timed pop ups load. I have found code and edited it to what I had thought it should do, but it is only loading the last onLoad event. I am a designer and I have helped with making webpages, but Javascript is so far outside of what I can understand. I have already learned how to use the single pop up and spent a whiiile learning the timeouts, but I cannot seem to get it to work with multiple popup functions. If you have a moment, would you take a look? Thank you :)

h

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>H's Page 1</title>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Ronnie T. Moore, Editor -->
<!-- Web Site:  The JavaScript Source -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
closetime = 3; // Close window after __ number of seconds?
// 0 = do not close, anything else = number of seconds

function Start1(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + WIDTH + ",height=" + HEIGHT;
preview = window.open(URL, "preview", windowprops);
if (closetime) setTimeout("preview.close();", closetime*1000);
}

function doPopup1() {
    url = "http://www.google.com";
    width = 1680;  // width of window in pixels
    height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
    delay = 10;    // time in seconds before popup opens
    timer = setTimeout("Start1(url, width, height)", delay*1000);
    }   

closetime = 3; // Close window after __ number of seconds?


function Start2(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + WIDTH + ",height=" + HEIGHT;
preview = window.open(URL, "preview", windowprops);
if (closetime) setTimeout("preview.close();", closetime*1000);
}


function doPopup2() {
    url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    width = 1680;  // width of window in pixels
    height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
    delay = 5;    // time in seconds before popup opens
    timer = setTimeout("Start2(url, width, height)", delay*1000);
    }



//  End -->
</script>

<!-- STEP TWO: Insert the onLoad event handler into your BODY tag  -->

<!-- Script Size:  1.27 KB -->

</head>

<body OnLoad="doPopup1(); doPopup2();">
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing up procedural and functional styles. For example, your variable `closetime` is in global scope and should only exist once. Defining it before a function definition then re-defining it before a different function doesn't do what you think it does. BTW also you should introduce local variables with the `var` keyword. I hate to say it, but I'm going to have to suggest getting a Javascript book. There is just too much to cover in a StackOverflow answer; to write Javascript, you must know Javascript!

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. I shall take out the second closetime. I would love to learn more, but this is not something I will have time to spend learning the code itself, hopefully I will have more time next project.

Comment: I wonder if you could negotiate to get paid more for non-design work!

Comment: ^ I definitely agree! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first, let me give my condolences to you for having a boss who orders you to use popups... they're hateful :( anyways, if you wanna scare of visitors, i guess that's up to you. so here goes:

you're overwriting the url variables with your timeouts. the following works for me in firefox though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>H's Page 1</title>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            <!-- Original:  Ronnie T. Moore, Editor -->
            <!-- Web Site:  The JavaScript Source -->

            <!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
            <!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

            <!-- Begin
            closetime = 3; // Close window after __ number of seconds?
            // 0 = do not close, anything else = number of seconds

            function Start1(URL1, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
                windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + WIDTH + ",height=" + HEIGHT;
                preview = window.open(URL1, "preview", windowprops);
                if (closetime) {
                    setTimeout("preview.close();", closetime*1000);
                }
            }

            function doPopup1() {
                url1 = "http://www.google.com";
                width = 1680;  // width of window in pixels
                height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
                delay = 5;    // time in seconds before popup opens
                timer = setTimeout("Start1(url1, width, height)", delay*1000);
            }   

            function Start2(URL2, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
                windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + WIDTH + ",height=" + HEIGHT;
                preview = window.open(URL2, "preview", windowprops);
                if (closetime) {
                    setTimeout("preview.close();", closetime*1000);
                }
            }

            function doPopup2() {
                url2 = "http://www.yahoo.com";
                width = 1680;  // width of window in pixels
                height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
                delay = 10;    // time in seconds before popup opens
                timer = setTimeout("Start2(url2, width, height)", delay*1000);
            }

            //  End -->
        </script>

        <!-- STEP TWO: Insert the onLoad event handler into your BODY tag  -->

        <!-- Script Size:  1.27 KB -->

    </head>

    <body OnLoad="doPopup1(); doPopup2();">
        <p>My page text.</p>
        <p>My page text.</p>
        <p>My page text.</p>
        <p>My page text.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a bit, and created closures to handle your settimeout's better.
If you ever have to modify this, I think you'll find calling settimeout in this manner easier (you'll run into less issues with global variables).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>H's Page 1</title>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Ronnie T. Moore, Editor -->
<!-- Web Site:  The JavaScript Source -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin

var closetime = 3; // Close window after __ number of seconds?
// 0 = do not close, anything else = number of seconds


function Start1(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
    var windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + WIDTH + ",height=" + HEIGHT;
    var preview = window.open(URL, "preview", windowprops);
    if (closetime) {
        var timer = setTimeout(preview.close, closetime * 1000);
    }
}

function doPopup1() {

    function startCaller() {
        var url = "http://www.google.com";
        var width = 1680; // width of window in pixels
        var height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
        Start1(url, width, height);
    }
    var delay = 10; // time in seconds before popup opens    
    setTimeout(startCaller, delay * 1000);
}


function doPopup2() {

    function startCaller() {
        var url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        var width = 1680; // width of window in pixels
        var height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
        Start1(url, width, height);
    }
    var delay = 5; // time in seconds before popup opens    
    setTimeout(startCaller, delay * 1000);
}


//  End -->
</script>

<!-- STEP TWO: Insert the onLoad event handler into your BODY tag  -->

<!-- Script Size:  1.27 KB -->

</head>

<body onload="doPopup1(); doPopup2();">
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a closure to make the window.close work in the timeout. Not that this would not work if you just open the html file with your browser at least on FF3.6) but would work of you put it on your webserver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>H's Page 1</title>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Ronnie T. Moore, Editor -->
<!-- Web Site:  The JavaScript Source -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin

var closetime = 3; // Close window after __ number of seconds?
// 0 = do not close, anything else = number of seconds

function doPopup(url, delay) {
    var width = 1680; // width of window in pixels
    var height = 1050; // height of window in pixels
    setTimeout(function () {
        var windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + width + ",height=" + height;
        var preview = window.open(url, "preview", windowprops);
        if (closetime) {  setTimeout(function(){
            preview.close();
        }, closetime * 1000); }
    } , delay * 1000);
}


//  End -->
</script>

<!-- STEP TWO: Insert the onLoad event handler into your BODY tag  -->

<!-- Script Size:  1.27 KB -->

</head>

<body onload="doPopup('http://www.google.com', 1); doPopup('http://www.yahoo.com', 2);">
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
<p>My page text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```